# ¿Cómo hacer para que el programa siga su ejecucion?

Tags: c, unix

Necesito ayuda con lo siguiente. ¿Cómo puedo conseguir que el programa no termine su ejecucion, cuando se a encontrado un error en la funcion num_pipes? Lo que quiero es que el prompt dentro del while loop de main() siga su ejecución.

Hago test con lo siguiente: a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | k. Lo cual debe mostrar el mensaje "pipeline too deep".

```
 void num_pipes(char *strings)
{
    int i;
    int pipes;
    for(i=0; strings[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(strings[i]=='|')
            pipes++;
    }
  if(pipes > 10)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "pipeline too deep\n");
    exit(1);
  }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *cmd_line;
    while(1)
    { 
        cmd_line = readline("Shell_script: ");

        if(cmd_line == NULL)
        {  /* Exit on Ctrl-D */
            printf("\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        num_pipes(cmd_line);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quita exit(1) de tu función num_pipes, la llamada a exit siempre termina con la ejecución de tu programa